# LiveCycle need to program submit by email button so attachment in xml/pdf is unique

Tags: livecycle

for example, if i send this form to john smith and he enters his name in a field in the form and clicks 'submit by email", the attachment should be john.pdf or john.xml.

I get some weird documents like _ac324cxdsf and etc...

How do i fix this? Please let me know. thanx

Answer (score 0):

here is the [LiveCycle Designer submit email button description](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/000181.html)

The file that your users have downloaded is most likely in their temp folder. Acrobat/Reader then calls Outlook to create a new message with that file as the attachment. In order to use a different filename, the script in the form would have to change it, which would be a file system operation. Due to security reasons, Acrobat/Reader is not allowed to let PDFs do filesystem operations unless the user authorizes it. Seems like more trouble than it's worth to just rename the PDF attachment. What about having an automated inbox that checks the attachment when it comes in for the name, then renames it on your end?

-John